# How do I use javascript to force an embedded Flash movie player to exit full screen mode

Tags: javascript, flash, fullscreen

I have an embedded Flash movie player. I'm also using [Timeout Dialog](http://rigoneri.github.com/timeout-dialog.js/) to set a timer that has a popup which will warn people before they are automatically logged off. The session timeout dialog does not display on top of the full screen mode Flash player so even if people are watching the Flash player they are not warned they are about to get logged off.

Using alert() breaks people out of the full screen mode but it isn't very attractive. Are there any other hacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function `exitFullScreen`in Flash to exit fullscreen mode and do this in Flash:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.addCallback("exitFullScreen", exitFullScreen);
```

Then you can invoke `exitFullScreen` on the flash object in JavaScript.

see: [ExternalInterface Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing the flash object, you could use ExternalInterface (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to let javascript call the flash player, and the flash player can set the display state to normal (`Stage["displayState"] = "normal";`).

If you aren't developing the player, you might be able to set `allowfullscreen` on the flash element to `false`.